# Formatting code

Tags: support

I attempted to post a question and am getting the error message:

- Your question couldn’t be submitted / Resolve 1 issues before posting
- Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

I'm going to post the entire body of the question below and see if it posts here. If so, I'd like to know why it's not posting on Stack Overflow.

---

In the Microsoft documentation for Office VBA, the page on the function `VarType()` lists its return values. And there is a page with a list of "VarType constants" without any explanation of what they are or where they are used, but the list is the same as the return values of `VarType()`:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/vartype-constants

In the Microsoft documentation for .Net VBA, there is a page that lists values of the "VariantType Enum" and says that this ennum "Indicates the type of a variant object, returned by the VarType function.":

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.varianttype

There is a page on .NET VBA functions:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/

with links to categories of functions, but none of those categories seems to include a function `VarType()`. So my first question: **Is there a function **`VarType()`** specific to .NET? If so, where is it documented?**

Those lists of Office and .Net `VarType()` values are almost, but not completely, the same:

|  | VariantType Enum (.Net) | VarType constants (Office) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Count of items | 20 | 19 |
| 2 | Short | vb[Integer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/integer-data-type) |
| 3 | Integer (= [vbInteger](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbinteger)) | vb[Long](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/long-data-type) |
| 18 | Char (= vbChar) | Absent |
| 20 | Long (= [vbLong](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vblong)) | vb[LongLong](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/longlong-data-type) |

So apparently, the function `VarType()` is subtly different in Office and .NET. And some of the constants defined for return values have the same names but different meanings in the two platforms. That seems sloppy.

I work in the Office programs, Excel and Access. I've never worked in .NET, and I suppose if I ever port VBA code from Office to .NET, I'm going to need to be careful about those differences in `VarType()` values.

In the listing of VariantType Enum values, most of the values are stated to be equivalent to a Visual Basic constant `vb...`. In the table above, I have shown those equivalences in brackets. Those constants appear to be the fields of the Constants Class:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.constants

That class has fields `vbInteger` and `vbLong`, and I've provided links in the table to the documentation pages on those fields. But the class does not appear to have a field, `vbChar`.

So my second question: **Does the constant **`vbChar`** exist? If so, what is it? Is it documented?**

Comment: Okay, it worked here. I just copy-pasted the exact text content of the question I attempted to post on StackOverflow. Why does it post here and not there?

Comment: Meta doesn't follow the same restrictions. There's a dupe for this

Comment: Would be real nice if they fixed the code detection so it doesn't trigger on tables, but I'm not optimistic that's going to happen in the near foreseeable future. You could try formatting the table as code just to get it posted, it may be possible for a 2k user to fix it after the fact. (though I don't remember if 2k users can bypass it after it's posted, but it does work for "too much code". /shrug)

Comment: Okay, thanks. The answer on that dupe got me through: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70815236/vba-a-is-there-a-different-vartype-in-net-than-in-office-b-what-is-vbch